# Is it possible to use PhoneGap/Cordova to make a screen lock?

Tags: cordova

Very, very new to PhoneGap/ordova. As in the subject, is it possible to use PhoneGap/Cordova to make a screen lock? So someone have to use my app to be able to unlock the screen, so my app will be the default way of unlocking the screen...

Comment: I would be incredibly surprised if you were able to do this in iOS, but you might be able to do something in Android, but I doubt it as well. If anything you're going to probably have to write your own custom plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view a plugin for unlock here
https://github.com/kitolog/cordova-plugin-screen-locker
Usage:

1. Add cordova plugin `cordova plugin add https://github.com/kitolog/cordova-plugin-screen-locker.git`
2. Call unlock method `var successCallback = function(){ console.log('success'); //do some staff };
   var errorCallback = function(e){ console.log('error'); console.log(e); };
   window.screenLocker.unlock(successCallback, errorCallback);`

Works only android, ios and windows phone will be added soon

Answer (score 3):

Cordova uses a WebView inside a native app frame to make it look like a native app. This means it's going to be impossible to achieve this without writing some native code outside the realm of HTML / JS / CSS that you'd normally use within a Cordova App.

So in short this won't be possible unless you write your app natively or a plugin that uses native code for Cordova.