# Unlock Screen in intel xdk

Tags: javascript, lockscreen, intel-xdk

I'm currently making an emergency response using intel xdk and it is a mobile platform. My adviser want's me to implement an unlock screen that will directly go to my application. my problem is that is there an api or a third party that can  be implemented to my project? i'm just new in intel xdk.

Answer (score 0):

See this posting which is asking the reverse > [Is it possible to use PhoneGap/Cordova to make a screen lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502157/is-it-possible-to-use-phonegap-cordova-to-make-a-screen-lock) < If this can be done via the native API you'll need to write (or find) a Cordova/PhoneGap plugin to get you access to that feature, but I don't think it's possible on most platforms. You might have to use a notification feature, instead. Android 5 introduced notifications that make it easier to get past the lock screen, but I've never seen an app that can directly bypass the lock screen, that would amount to a security risk.

Comment: Thnx bro. is there a plugin that can config/create an intent filter like on activation call. like emergency call? i mean making our own activation call or number to open the application while locked?